# Bundle:Install Failing in Capistrano - Permissions or missing repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano

So I have the following deploy file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "siteName.com", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :rvm_install_type, :stable
before "deploy", "rvm:install_rvm"

set :rvm_ruby_string, "2.1.0"
before "deploy", "rvm:install_ruby"

require "rvm/capistrano"

set :application, "appName"
set :user, "UserName"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:GitHubUser/GitRepo.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
# after "deploy", "deploy:install_gems"
after "deploy", "deploy:sync_data"

namespace :rails do
  task :console, :roles => :app do
    hostname = find_servers_for_task(current_task).first
    exec "ssh -l #{user} #{hostname} -t 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rails console #{rails_env}'"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Start Application"
  task :start, :roles => :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Stop Application (NOOP)"
  task :stop, :roles => :app, except: {no_release: true} do
  end

  # desc "Install gems"
  # task :install_gems, roles: :app do
  # # This is a rather long command call. We Essentially tell promiscuous to publish and and all tables that need to be.
  #   exec 'bundle install'
  # end

  desc "sync data from this app to any other app listening"
  task :sync_data, roles: :app do
  # This is a rather long command call. We Essentially tell promiscuous to publish and and all tables that need to be.
    exec 'bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::User.all" && bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::Role.all" && bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::Permission.all" && bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::ApiKey.all"'
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end

  task :setup_secrets_config, roles: :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/secrets.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config", "deploy:setup_secrets_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  task :symlink_secrets_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config", "deploy:symlink_secrets_config"

  # desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
   task :check_revision, roles: :web do
     unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
       puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
       puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
       exit
     end
   end
   before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

The specific issue I am having is when it gets to:

```
 * 2014-07-07 19:06:26 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/UserName/ApplicationName/releases/20140708010625 && bundle install --gemfile /home/UserName/ApplicationName/releases/20140708010625/Gemfile --path /home/UserName/ApplicationName/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["SiteName.com"]
    [SiteName.com] executing command
 ** [out :: SiteName.com] ERROR: Repository not found.
 ** [out :: SiteName.com] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 ** [out :: SiteName.com] 
 ** [out :: SiteName.com] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 ** [out :: SiteName.com] and the repository exists.
 ** [out :: SiteName.com] Retrying git clone 'git@github.com:UserName/Repo.git' "/home/UserName/aisisplatform/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/Xaaron-e125fcc5e1c3bbf107442cab2dd93d453c419fb9" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:UserName/Repo.git' "/home/UserName/ApplicationName/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/Xaaron-e125fcc5e1c3bbf107442cab2dd93d453c419fb9" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/UserName/ApplicationName/releases/20140708010625 has failed.
```

It will do this over and over again until it finally gives up and quits. so I thought, ok I don't have permission - or do I, because I use two different users on my server, one for deploying and one for regular server maintenance - I did `sudo -i -u UserName` and under that user I wen't to `/home/UserName/ApplicationName/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/` and ran `git clone ...` and it pulled down the repository in question just fine. No issues.

I then decided, to go to the `ApplicationName/current/` and add the gem in question to the gem file and ran `bundle install` and it worked fine. It installed the gem.

So is there a way to shut off bundle:install so I can do it my self on the server, because this really seems like it doesn't want to work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do bundle:install yourself on the server. Get the permissions right and do it the correct way.

I assume when you say "I did sudo -i -u UserName and under that user", you're referring to the 'regular server maintenance' user. Is that correct?

If so, it looks like the user you're deploying with DOESN'T have permission to access your github repo, but the user you're doing regular server maintenance work with DOES have permission.

Most likely, that means that in GitHub, you've added your SSH key for the maintenance user, but not the deploy user. Go to https://github.com/settings/ssh and check if that's the case.

To debug this issue, I'd be forgetting about Capistrano for now, and just logging in manually as the DEPLOY user, and trying to do a `git clone`. Once you get that working, Capistrano should just work.

Comment: The deploy user is what gets logged into when i do `sudo -i -u CapDeployUserName`. Also the Deploy user has my macs ssh key, because I can do `ssh CapDeployUserName@site.com` and be logged in with no password request. I can, through ssh log in as CapDeployUserName - through the steps listed and do a git clone on the repo in question and have **NO ISSUES** pulling down the repo.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what the issue could be then. I would update your question to make it clear you're sudo-ing as the deploy user, not the maintenance one, because it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: I fixed the issue but in a very odd way, see in one tab on my mac I had to do `ssh -v RegularUser@site.com` from there I could run, in a separate tab, `bundle exec cap deploy` and it all worked as I expec. See CapDeployUserName is my capistrano deploy user on my server, while RegularUser is the user I use to log in, do server updates and so on ... so this very odd, but it worked either way ....